# remove local path from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

Trying to make a simple get request but does not work since the local path is added to the passed in url so the following code :

```
$.get('www.google.com', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Error is given as : Failed to load resources : http://localhost:63342/testing/www.google.com the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). How would one remove the local host that jquery is implicitly adding to the url?

Comment: Prepend your path with //

Comment: you need to specify a protocol if you want to get from a different domain ... `//` as previous comment suggests, means "same protocol as page" - i.e. `http://` in a http served page and `https://` in a https served page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not including a `protocol identifier` causes the AJAX request to assume your specifying only the `path` part of the URL.

A http/https agnostic way (also called `protocol relative`) of specifying protocol is `//`, for example:

```
$.get('//www.google.com', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```